# having issues with fprintf C in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, printf

I am attempting to output with fprintf within C++ in Xcode on Mac for the purposes of Physics project. Previously I have used Turbo C++ on a PC and had no issues with similar outputs as as I wrote up below... I am trying to send data to a .csv file in order to create graphs/charts in xcel, but the debugger HATES the output I attempting. Can someone PLEASE help me and tell me how to send output out of xcode and into either xcel or mac's numbers program? What is wrong with my code? THANKS I AM AT MY WIT'S END!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    int ia,ja,ib=1,jb=1,n=1,t=1;
    float Ia[25],Ja[25],C[25][25],Wbb[25][25];
    float xl[25][25],xr[25][25],Pr[25][25],Nr[25][25];
    float max,r1,H=0;

    max=RAND_MAX;
    FILE * Project1;
    Project1 = fopen ("Users/Dave/Desktop/Project1.csv","w");

    Ia[n]=3;
    Ja[n]=3;
    for(t=1;t<100;++t) //time step counter
    {
        n=1;
        for(n=1;n<26;++n) //# of states to look at
        {
            ia=Ia[n];
            ja=Ja[n];
            ib=1;

            for(ib=1;ib<6;++ib) //determine I[n]'s C[ia][ja] values (initially will be the same due to ICs)
            {
                jb=1;
                for(jb=1;jb<6;++jb)
                {
                    C[ia][ja]=100*(ia-ib)^2+100*(ja-jb)^2+1;
                }
            }
            fprintf(Project1, "%d,%d,%d,%f\n",n,ia,ja,C[ia][ja]);

            ib=1;
            for(ib=1;ib<6;++ib) //determine Wsrs and delta x's for each system I[n] {
            {
                jb=1;
                for(jb=1;jb<6;++jb)
                {
                    Wbb[ib][jb]=C[ia][ja]/((100)*(ia-ib)^2+100*(ja-jb)^2+1);
                    xl[1][1]=0;
                    xr[ib][jb]=xl[ib][jb]+Wbb[ib][jb];
                    fprintf(Project1,"%d,%d,%f,%f,%f",ib,jb,Wbb[ib][jb],xl[ib][jb],xr[ib][jb]);
                    xl[ib][jb+1]=xr[ib][jb];
                }
            }

            r1=rand()/max; //randomly select new state and determine it's ib,jb value and reassign to new ia, ja at next time step
            ib=1;
            for(ib=1;ib<6;++ib)
            {
                jb=1;
                for(jb=1;jb<6;++jb)
                {
                    if(r1<xr[ib][jb] & r1>xl[ib][jb])
                        Nr[ib][jb]++;
                    Ia[n]=ib;
                    Ja[n]=jb;
                }
            }
        }

        ib=1;
        for(ib=1;ib<6;++ib)
        {
            jb=1;
            for(jb=1;jb<6;++jb)
            {
                Pr[ib][jb]=Nr[ib][jb]/25;
                H=Pr[ib][jb]*log(Pr[ib][jb])+H; //Compute Total Entropy Function of all systems by adding each systems entropy
            }
        }

        fprintf(Project1,"%f",H); //print out the Entropy at each time step
    }   
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: This looks like FORTRAN translated into C :).  One serious problem: `Wbb[ib][jb]=C[ia][ja]/((100)*(ia-ib)^2+100*(ja-jb)^2+1);`.  C/C++ doesn't have an "^" "power-of" operator.  You need to substitute the "exp()" math function instead.  Here's a list of [C/C++ operators](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40F_HTML/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_059.HTM).

Comment: @paulsm4 I agree, which therefore brings to doubt the validity of the claim *"Previously I have used Turbo C++ on a PC and had no issues with similar outputs as as I wrote up below..."* Not even Turbo C++ is off-the-reservation far enough to override the XOR operator as an "exponent" operator.

Comment: "the debugger HATES the output I attempting" -- What on Earth does that mean? How exactly does the debugger express its hatred? And `"Users/Dave/Desktop/Project1.csv"` is a relative path name, valid only if you're in the parent directory of `Users`; you probably want `"/Users/Dave/..."`. You're not checking whether the `fopen()` call succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few issues here that I see, in this line you are using the wrong quotes:

```
Project1 = fopen (“Users/Dave/Desktop/Project1.csv”,”w”);
```

should be:

```
Project1 = fopen ("Users/Dave/Desktop/Project1.csv","w");
```

As someone pointed out C++ does not have a `power` operator, the `^` is a `bitwise exclusive or`, you need to use the `pow` function instead, so this line:

```
C[ia][ja]=100*(ia-ib)^2+100*(ja-jb)^2+1;
```

would be:

```
C[ia][ja]=100*pow((ia-ib),2)+100*pow((ja-jb),2)+1;
```

Also the `&` operator is a `bitwise and` and in the following context I think you meant `&&` which is a `logical and`, in this case they will do the same thing though:

```
 if(r1<xr[ib][jb] & r1>xl[ib][jb])
```

Also if you are developing in C++ I would use the C++ versions of the header files:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
```

Comment: thanks for helping!  yeah, the exp thing was carryover from mathematica and the quotes was because i had to write it up on travel in a word document.  it succeeds now in the build, but is still having issues when running...